# Swap Axes of Violin plot

Tags: plot, julia, violin-plot, statsplots.jl

I am trying to create Violin Plots using the StatsPlots.jl library.
However, I would like to have the returned Violin plot to be *horizontal* instead of *vertical* as I want to show the distribution of a variable (e.g. Temperature) for different heights, eg. at 1000m, 2000m, 3000m ...

So it would be nice if the height was at the y-Axis while the temperature distribution was on the x-Axis.
Is there a way to swap the axes of a Plots.Plot struct, or is there an argument I could pass to violin() that does the trick?

Comment: Looks like this was added at some point but got reverted https://github.com/JuliaPlots/StatsPlots.jl/pull/492

Comment: That is unfortunate. When I try the keyword `orientation` anyways, it produces something incorrect and I get the warning that `orientation` is deprecated and that `permute` should be used instead, but this is not defined.